# CSS Flex Center and Masonry JS Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm making a simple image gallery using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

https://jsfiddle.net/q6ugvqrg/

Masonry example images are in a div container with `max-width` and `margin auto` center.

The html `body` is set to css `flex`, used for other elements on my page.

Masonry stops working if I use `flex` and `margin auto` center.

**Masonry CSS Conflict**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Add that css body code to my jsfiddle example to see.

[image: masonry gallery]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Gallery -->
  <div class="gallery" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 130 }'>

    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rl9CUbF.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LwzLtKh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V7xsUgj.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pCfp0Gk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LwzLtKh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rl9CUbF.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pCfp0Gk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V7xsUgj.jpg">
    </div>

  </div> <!-- Gallery End -->

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {

  background: #eadcca;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

**JS**

https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js

```
$('.gallery').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 130,
  isFitWidth: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.container` needs a width. Since you have a `max-width` defined, you can use `width: 100%;`

```js
$('.gallery').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 130,
  isFitWidth: true
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {

  background: #eadcca;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Gallery -->
  <div class="gallery" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 130 }'>
  
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rl9CUbF.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LwzLtKh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V7xsUgj.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pCfp0Gk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LwzLtKh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rl9CUbF.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/pCfp0Gk.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/V7xsUgj.jpg">
    </div>
    
  </div> <!-- Gallery End -->
  
</div>
```